# Configuration Error when taking project from local host to server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

An error that arises when I take a vb project Visual Studio 2010 that works on my local machine to a server. How precisely would I work around it?

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 24:       ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
Line 25:     -->
Line 26:     <authentication mode="Windows" />
Line 27:     <!--
Line 28:        The <customErrors> section enables configuration
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a virtual directory on the server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwk103ab%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: if we run project on local server then its required to create virtual directory on server

Comment: No, you could use the built-in server (Cassini) in VS. But it's always better to develop in an environment as similar as possible to the production one where it's eventually going to run.